# Update TextArea While Processing

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my current setup, when a user presses a button, it runs a specific function. Throughout that function, I would like to let the user know the function's status, by outputting information to them. On the same page, I have a textarea. When I want to update the user, I use the following function:

```
public static void appendToTextbox(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTextArea textArea, String message)
{
     textArea.InnerText = textArea.InnerText + "\r\n" + message;
}
```

However, this poses the problem that the textarea is only actually updated once all of the processing has finished. I get all of the messages at once, instead of one-by-one, which really defeats the purpose. I know that the data is server-side, and I'm trying to push information to the client, which probably requires AJAX of some kind, but I'm not sure how to modify my function to update the textarea exactly when I execute the function.

Comment: You might need to look into something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net) which is an open source project maintained by Microsoft. It allows you to send notifications to and from the browser from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications to the client like this are not directly handled by the ASP.NET framework, but can be readily implemented with tools like [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr/).

SignalR lets you establish connections with a client browser (or other apps) that can be used as bi-directional message pipes.  Clients can call methods on the server and vice versa.

In the case of a progress notification your client would request the notifications by calling a method on the SignalR hub.  When your process wants to feed information back to the client it calls the server-side code that notifies clients and a JavaScript method is called at each listening client.

Here's some sample code for a SignalR progress Hub:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace ProjectNamespace
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {
        public Task Register(string processID)
        {
            return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, processID);
        }

        public Task Unregister(string processID)
        {
            return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, processID);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Register` and `Unregister` methods will be called by clients to request that they be included in notifications for a particular `processID`.  This will be generated by your code that starts off the process, passed to the client, which then registers interest via the SignalR hub.

On the client side you would then have a script containing something like this:

```
// register a function that can be called by the server 
$.connection.progressHub.client.updateProgress = function (mesage, value) {
        $("div.progress").text(message + ": " + value);
    }

// invoke the 'Register' method on the hub
$.connection.progressHub.server.register("process_1234");
```

And to send a message to the client(s) listening to any particular processID:

```
public static class Progress
{
    public static void Notify(string processID, string message, float value)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
        context.Clients.Group(processID).updateProgress(message, value);
    }
}
```

Any time you call `Progress.Notify` the `message` and `value` parameters will be sent to the connected clients that have registered for notifications on the specific `processID`, which will result in the client-side function above being called.  All registered clients for that `processID` will get the message and update their display, so you can have multiple clients displaying the same information.

If you haven't used SignalR before I would definitely encourage you to give it a try.  You can do lots of fun things with it.

Comment: Very interesting - I will have to do a lot of reading on SignalR, but this seems to meet exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!